# Rechargeable batteries on GPS dev boards and how is it getting charged?

Tags: batteries, gps

Almost all of the GPS dev boards have a tiny button/coin battery (for hot startup) and the specs claim that is it rechargeable using a simple diode and register circuit.

Here are a couple of examples of the DEV boards
NEO-6M - [https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-GY-NEO6MV2-Controller-Ceramic-Antenna/dp/B01D1D0F5M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D1D0F5M)
ATGM336H - [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B67XRQLP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B67XRQLP)

My question is, that kind of battery is this that is rechargeable and whats the diode and register circuit that charges it? Google search tells me that a LiPo charging circuit is much most complicated. And even if what they claim is true, how many charging cycles will these take?

Comment: Please clarify _”rechargeable using a simple diode and register circuit”_.

Answer (score 1):

While Lithium-based cells require rather precise and complex circuits, other chemistries are much more forgiving in this regard.

E.g. NiCd and NiMH cells can be overcharged as much as one wants with no ill effects as long as the charging current is limited to whatever the datasheet says (usually something like C/10).

Of course, charging circuit containing a single resistor is not very efficient, but a current of half mA is usually livable with in a module that drains e.g. 15mA as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

There are several chemistries. We can't of course know what exact batteries the modules you link to will use so we can't have their data sheets and provide an exact answer.

But for example, "VL" button cells such as [VL1220](https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/products/pt/coin_rechargeable_lithium/models/VL1220) are Vanadium Pentoxide Lithium rechargeable batteries.

They can be charged by simply having a resistor to limit current and a diode to only charge the battery from 3.3V supply in forward direction and prevent discharging in the reverse direction.

And they are rated for up to 1000 charging cycles if the discharge depth is not more than 10% of capacity.